# Does firebase-database fetches data when ran locally?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Does `firebase-database` fetches data when cloud functions are ran locally?
This is working perfectly fine when deployed, but not working at all on my local machine.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
const readAndWriteToFirebase = async (payload, admin1) => {
  const dmac = Object.keys(payload)[0];
  try {
    console.log('got called')
    const db = admin.database()
    const ref = db.ref(`users/${dmac}`);
    const snapshot = await ref.once('value')
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  } catch (error) {
    // do some fancy thing with the error here
    console.error(error)
  }
}

// this function is calling the above function
export const subscribeToPubSub = functions.pubsub.topic('not-test').onPublish(async (event, context) => {
  const pubSubMessage = event.json;
  try {
    // JSON.stringify(pubSubMessage);
    // admin.initializeApp();
    const firebasePayload = parseTopicPayload(pubSubMessage);
    console.log(firebasePayload)
    return readAndWriteToFirebase(firebasePayload, admin)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('PubSub message was not JSON', e);
    return e
  }
});
```

now to run it locally:

`npm start`

> "start": "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=\"/home/haroonkhan/Workspace/Personal/Dev/abc-functions/functions/secret/abc-beta-12345678.json\"; npm run shell",

there is nothing in the console regarding `database`.

this function here is invoked on my pub-sub trigger cloud function, it fetches data from `firebase-database`.

And yes, I have downloaded the service account key from [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=xyz), successfully running the pub-sub trigger function locally.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes. When you access the database through `admin.database()` it is supposed to access the Firebase Database. But it's hard to say what's going on for you with the limited information provided. How do you wrap this code up on Cloud Functions? How do you invoke the simulator? Is there any relevant debug output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated the question.

Comment: Is your function being invoked at all? I.e. if you put a `console.log` on the first statement *inside* the function, does it log the output from that line?

Comment: yup, everything else is working. console.log is working too. just the firebase-database part.

Comment: You're not returning anything *from* `readAndWriteToFirebase`, which is always suspicious, especially since you then return it from `subscribeToPubSub`.